# Changing the movement speed along a spline dynamically during runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-input

I've been playing with this player movement script and I need to change a part of its functionality, but I'm now exactly how to get it to do what I need it to. Currently the player moves forward automatically along a spline at a fixed speed on Awake. Changing the movementSpeed variable in the inspector doesn't currently change the player speed during runtime. The new functionality that I need includes: being able to change the movementSpeed during runtime with a slider input (or any variable float range) so that I can dynamically change the movementSpeed at any time during gameplay. Any guidance on this incorporating this function would be amazing! Thanks in advance.

```cs
[SerializeField, Self] InputReader input;

[SerializeField] Transform followTarget;
[SerializeField] float followDistance = 2f;
[SerializeField] Vector2 movementLimit = new Vector2(x:2f, y:2f);
[SerializeField] float movementRange = 5f;
[SerializeField] float movementSpeed;
[SerializeField] float smoothTime = 0.2f;

[SerializeField] float maxRoll = 15f;
[SerializeField] float rollSpeed = 2f;

Vector3 velocity;
float roll;

void Update()
{
    // Calculate the target position based on the follow distance and the target's position
    Vector3 targetPos = followTarget.position + followTarget.forward * -followDistance;

    // Apply smooth damp to the player's position
    Vector3 smoothedPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPos, ref velocity, smoothTime);

    // Calculate the new local position
    Vector3 localPos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(smoothedPos);
    localPos.x += input.Move.x * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime * movementRange;
    localPos.y += input.Move.y * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime * movementRange;

    //Clamp the local position
    localPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(localPos.x, -movementLimit.x, movementLimit.x);  
    localPos.y = Mathf.Clamp(localPos.y, -movementLimit.y, movementLimit.y);

    //Update the player's position
    transform.position = transform.TransformPoint(localPos);
    
    //Match the player's rotation to the follow target's rotation
    transform.rotation = followTarget.rotation;

    //Match the roll of the player to the input
    roll = Mathf.Lerp(roll, input.Move.x * maxRoll, Time.deltaTime * rollSpeed);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, roll);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[SerializeField] [Range(0,x)] float movementSpeed;` set x to any value you want

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but when I move this slider in the inspector during play mode the speed doesn't change, it just remains at the original set speed. How do I get the speed to actually change based on the slider settings?

Comment: Have you tried debug.log(movementspeed) in your update Method and change the value in inspector ? the value in the inspector should override the original one

Comment: I have. debug is showing the values change as I move the slider, but the player doesn't change speed at all. I'm kind of stuck, what am I missing?

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue and realized that when you debug.log
`input.Move.x * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;`

the value is so small to notice any change what i did is removed * Time.deltaTime